# All groups list with additional boolean field showing user membership

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to get the list of all available groups with an additional Boolean field showing if a particular user is member of that group.

```
#This give me all groups related to the user "myuser"
mygroup = myuser.groups.all()
```

The result is a list of id, groupname related to the user "myuser".

How can I have a list of all groups (including those not part of mygroup) with evidence of membership for "myuser" on additional Boolean field (user_membership)?

**id, groupname, user_membership(true/false)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [a conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
Group.objects.annotate(user_membership=Case(
    When(user=myuser, then=Value(True)),
    default=Value(False),
    output_field=BooleanField(),
))
```

This would return all groups with an additional `user_membership` field containing `True` or `False` values.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you!